# Mapping composition

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, function-and-relation-composition

I have difficulties with this task:
Prove, that every mapping can be written as a composition of surjective and injective mapping.
So for example: $f \circ g = h$;
$f$ is surjective;
$g$ is injective;
$h$ represents every mapping.

Additional task is whether changing the order of mappings ($g \circ f$)  still became a mapping.

The thing i can prove and might be connected with the toppic is, that if $f\circ g =\text{identity}$, then $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write a map $h:X\to Y$ as the concatenation of

- the restriction $h|_{\mathrm{im}(h)}:X\to\mathrm{im}(h)$ (which is surjective), and
- the embedding $\iota:\mathrm{im}(h)\to Y$ (which is injective).

Here $\mathrm{im}(h)=\{h(x)\mid x\in X\}\subseteq Y$ denotes the *image* of $h$. It is not hard to see why $\iota\circ h|_{\mathrm{im}(h)}=h$ holds.

---

The other way around is possible too. Let $h:X\to Y$ and define $M:=X\,\dot\cup\, Y$. Then define maps $g:X\to M$ and $f:M\to Y$ via

$$g(x)=x,\qquad f(x)=\begin{cases}
h(x)&\text{for } x\in X\\
x&\text{for } x\in Y
\end{cases}.$$

Then $h=f\circ g$ with injective $g$ and surjective $f$.

Comment: thanks, i understand the first part clearly. in the second part, (it is true, what you have written) But let's assume that the domain and codomain of map h ale egual. There might be a problem if Im(h) is not a proper subset of codomain of h. And then it is not a function. Am i right ?

Comment: @martina If $h:X\to X$ then $h|_{\mathrm{im}(h)}:X\to\mathrm{im}(h)$ and $\iota:\mathrm{im}(h)\to X$. So $h_{\mathrm{im}(h)}\circ\iota:\mathrm{im}(h)\to\mathrm{im}(h)$ is a valid map. As long as domain and codomain fit together, composing works and gives a map. I do not know why you think there can result anything else than a map. What is your definition of a *mapping*? Note that when $\mathrm{cod}(h)=\mathrm{dom}(h)$, then $\mathrm{im}(h)$ is *always* a subset of $\mathrm{cod}(h)$. It might not be a proper subset, but why is this important?

Comment: Winter Yea you are right in this case. But i dont know if you understood my additional task properly. I have to prove or disprove taht every map can be written as a composition of surjective and injective map. (The first tas was injective and surjective)

Comment: @martina Oh I see. When you say "surjective and injective" then you mean this in *this specific order*. This was not clear to me and I will think about it. However, I would really appreciate a reformulation of your post as this is not very clear from the current formulation.

Comment: @martina I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ are mappings. Then the product or composition is a mapping $gf: A\to C$ with $gf(a) = g(f(a))$. In general, you can't reverse the order, because $g$ operates from $B$ to $C$, but the domain of $f$ is $A$, so $fg$ isn't even defined.

If we have a mapping $f:A\to B$, we want to show that there exist injective function $h$ and surjective function $g$ such that either $f = hg$ or $f = gh$.

Denote the set
$$f(A) = \{f(a) : a\in A\} $$

If we let $g :A\to f(A)\subseteq B$ be defined such that for every $a\in A$ $g(a) = f(a)$, then it is clear $g$ is surjective. Now we automatically obtain an injective function $h:f(A)\to B$ (how?)